# ST_Split and looping problems PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am a total PostGIS noob, and am having trouble understanding the finer points of SQL syntax. I am trying to take a large set of line data and clip it with a polygon. I then want to create a new table with the lines that are in the polygon I used to clip. When I run this I receive `ERROR: syntax error at or near "ST_Split"` I am not sure what is wrong with my syntax. I was hopping that some could explain to me what is wrong with this line of code. Additionally I hoping that some one could explain the looping and variable syntax. Coming form a python background it seems very complicated.

```
CREATE TABLE roads_clipped AS

ST_Split(
    (SELECT geom 
    FROM roads),
    (SELECT st_union 
    FROM iberian_peninsula)
);

CREATE TABLE roads_of_the_iberian_peninsula;

BEGIN
    FOR row IN 
        SELECT geom FROM roads_clipped
    LOOP
        IF ST_Contains(
                (SELECT st_union 
                FROM iberian_peninsula)
                ,row)
            THEN INSERT INTO roads_of_the_iberian_peninsula
                VALUES row;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```